# How to create an Excel macro to stop another macro and re-call it?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in an Excel file that runs on a timer of 30 seconds continously:

```
Sub autosync()

  Call syncSQL 'a sync function that copies data rows to database.
  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00.30"), "Sheet7.autosync"

End Sub
```

However there are times where errors occurs which stops the timer, so I want to create a button that not only resumes the timer but also terminates the old timer and replace it with a new timer. This is to avoid having multiple timers running at the same time.

```
Sub resetsync()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "Sheet7.autosync", False    '1. Stops the current timer
Call autosync  '2. Call back the timer

End Sub
```

However, when I test the button , it ignores step 1 and goes straight to step 2 creating 2 autosync processes. Am I missing something?

Comment: what is `TimeValue("00:00.30")` supposed to be?

Comment: Typically, you would use a public boolean that determines whether to start another  cycle. This could be toggled true/false by a button's sub.

Comment: It means run the sub 'syncSQL' every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like that

```
Option Explicit

Dim iTimerSet As Double

Public Sub StopTimer()

 On Error Resume Next ' Lazy programming
 Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "RunTimer", , False

End Sub

Public Sub RunTimer()

    ' Some Demo Code
    ' here you can put your code
    ' Call syncSQL
    MsgBox "Call syncSQL ", vbOKOnly, "Test"


    ' Code to start the timer
    ' example every 5 seconde
    iTimerSet = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "RunTimer"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. By itself the code works fine. But one question though... Is it possible to remove the option explicit code? Because its kinda messing up my other macros in the sheet.

Comment: Yes. Yes I can remove option explicit. But please let me know if there is any consequenses in doing so that I'm not aware of. Other than that it perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I recommend to use [`Option Explicit`](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html). It just makes sure that you declare each variable. By removing it the code above will still work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start a timer you need to store the scheduled time in a Gobal/Static variable: that's the value you need to use when you want to cancel that same timer.

See eg: bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/application-ontime.htm

```
Dim exTime
Sub autosync()

  Call syncSQL 'a sync function that copies data rows to database.
  exTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 30)
  Application.OnTime exTime, "Sheet7.autosync"

End Sub


Sub resetsync()
    'EDIT - needs the "Schedule" parameter name...
    Application.OnTime exTime, "Sheet7.autosync", Schedule:=False '1. Stops the current timer
    Call autosync  '2. Call back the timer

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not working. While the timer is running I click the resetsync button and it just creates another timer without removing the old one. now there are 2 timers running at the same time...

Comment: See my edit above - needs the "Schedule:=" parameter name, since when just passed by position the `False` ends up in the `LatestTime` slot